# Citizenship for a minor born abroad to a Canadian and residing outside Canada

Tags: citizenship, canadian-citizens

My daughter, a Canadian citizen from birth, is having a child outside Canada where she resides. She does not intend to return to Canada to live for some years. Can she obtain Canadian citizenship for her child. She is not married.

Answer (score 2):

If your daughter (the child's mother) was born in Canada, then her child is (most likely) also a Canadian citizen. See [Get proof of citizenship](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-citizenship/proof-citizenship.html) for instructions on how to apply for a Canadian citizenship certificate for the child.

Once your daughter has the Canadian citizenship certificate, then she can apply for a Canadian passport for the child.

If your daughter was born outside Canada, then the child would probably *not* be a Canadian citizen.

For more information, see [Canadian citizenship by descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_nationality_law#Canadian_citizenship_by_descent).